# What does each field in a typical sh error message mean? Ex. "sh: 1: ipconfig: not found"

Tags: shell, sh

I have been receiving Shell error messages, typically due to a bad command, etc., but have been unable to debug the cause of these messages due to not understanding the information being provided.

I have been looking for documentation, but have been unable to find any regarding the format of an sh error message.

Example:
If I use the following command, it will fail, due to no 'ipconfig' command being available:

```
$ sh -c "ipconfig"
sh: 1: ipconfig: not found
```

What I'd like to understand is what each 'field' in that message pertains to? I assume it is:

`[interpreter]: [???]: [command]: [error related to command]`

I can't for the life of me determine what the number refers to, and I can't be sure if my understanding of the other fields is accurate.

Context:
I am debugging a Python2.7 pytest script used for automation testing, and there are numerous points where this script is executing shell commands. However, the output I receive is:

```py
(32512, 'sh: 2: 2: not found')
```

I know that function being used to execute the shell script returns a tuple with status code and output. I know that that status code is essentially 'command not found', and the error message is also stating that. Another function is returning a string which is used for this command, and I assume what is happening is that somewhere along the way, a bad argument must have been passed and now the script is attempting to execute, what would basically be `sh -c "2"`. I can't be sure though, as these are a lot of assumptions I'm making from a limited understanding of this error message.

If anyone could please enlighten me as to what the fields in this error ACTUALLY mean I'd be forever grateful!!

Comment: It's the line number in the source file.

Comment: You can check sh *-c* argument option from the [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sh.1p.html) page:

-c    Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set from the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining argument operands.

Comment: In your second example, the line number is 2 and the command you try to execute is also `2`. Since there seemingly is no command named `2`  in your path, you get the error message _not found_. You neither show how you invoke your shell script, nor what is the content of the script, so one can't say much more from the description you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Like you surmise, the number refers to the line number; so the command which produces `sh: 2: 2: not found` would look something like

```
sh -c '#!/bin/sh
2'
```

(where obviously the first line could contain anything at all, or nothing).

If the error is unrelated to a specific command (killed by a signal, etc), the shell obviously won't attribute it to one. So the general form of an error message from the shell is really just

*shell:* *line number:* *error*

and of course, many errors will emanate from utilities which might or might not adhere to the convention to print

*utility:* *error message*

to standard error. In particular, many amateur scripts will fail to include their own identity in their error messages, and some even emit error messages to standard output instead of standard error.

For the record, the way to do this from your own shell scripts looks something like

```
echo "${0##*/}: error message" >&2
```

which would often get encapsulated in a function. (The [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${0##*/}` peels off any path prefix from the value of `$0`, which contains the name of the current script.)

Also, don't forget to `exit` with a non-zero result code to programmatically signal to the caller that your command did not succeed.